# Invariant Violation: "EnglishPlatform" has not been registered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

After git clone I tried to yarn install and start React Native project, it builds successfully but every time I start android emulator I get this error. Invariant Violation: "EnglishPlatform" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
  This happened after I lost access to my pc and switched to an older one, everything was fine before that, tried many methods but none of them helped  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NyoP.png)

I tried again to clone this repository. Reinstall the node_modules. Even create an empty project and transfer the files. Clearing the cache. Changing the index.js.

Comment: Can you try to cancel all metro server instances that are running and try again?

Comment: Clear all possible metro bundler cache with `npm start -c`

Comment: I checked everything and found that error is sent only when I wrap App with Provider with store. I cleared cache and started but it still sends